# How to sort products by price if some products have a discount price (SQL)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I'd like to order products by price - `ASC` and `DESC`, but some of the products will have a `discountprice` column in database filled in, and if so - they should be taken in to account in stead of the `price` field.

So currently I have this:
`SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY price ASC`, but how can I also attach something like `if (discountprice != '' AND discountprice != NULL) then use discount price` for the `ORDER` clause for that particular product?

Comment: Why discountprice != '' ? Isn't it a numeric datatype?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this way:

```
SELECT (price-IFNULL(discountprice,0)) as finalprice FROM products
ORDER BY finalprice ASC
```

If you are trying to order by the `discountprice` column, you can do it in two ways:

1. Using `IFNULL`:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM products
   ORDER BY IFNULL(discountprice, price) ASC
   ```
2. Using `COALESCE` :

   ```
   SELECT * FROM products
   ORDER BY COALESCE(discountprice, price) ASC
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Use `COALESCE` to pick first non-null value:

```
SELECT * FROM products
ORDER BY coalesce(discountprice, price) ASC
```

If you, for some reason, also has empty strings as NULL, use regular `CASE`:

```
SELECT * FROM products
ORDER BY CASE when discountprice is NOT NULL
                   or discountprice != '' THEN discountprice
              else price end ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY 
case when (discountprice != '' or discountprice != NULL) 
then
  (price-discountprice)
else
  price
end 
ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

Create virtual column. When you don't have discountprice, it column must be 0.
Order by this column.

```
SELECT *,(price - discountprice) as order_price FROM products  ORDER BY order_price ASC
```

You can cast to integer if it's necessary.